# Eigen sum in custom tensorflow C++ op with Eigen::half on GPUDevice

Tags: compiler-errors, tensorflow, eigen, nvcc

I'm trying to create a custom tensorflow Op. I have gotten some ops to works using https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html and normal C++.

The problem arises when using the Eigen C++ framework and its `.sum` reducer. It works for CPU with the `double`, `float` and `Eigen::half` types, but on the GPU it breaks when using `Eigen::half`, at compile time.

I have reduced the problem to a copy of the `l2loss_op` from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/kernels, where I have renamed `L2Loss` to `CustomL2Loss` (otherwise I get name conflicts). See: https://gist.github.com/AndreasMadsen/4335215cd4293daad3cad745bbeae82a

The error is quite long: https://gist.github.com/AndreasMadsen/5cd0579267f0bc3e5a1c21f2341d9ad6

Since it works for all other cases but `<GPUDevice, Eigen::half>` (confirmed by commenting the line out in `l2loss_op.cu.cc`) I was considering if this was a tensorflow issue. But I can compile tensorflow itself.

Comment: Can you try to call nvcc with -arch compute_35 ? The fact that nvcc doesn't know about __shfl_down seems to indicate that you're targeting an architecture that doesn't support 16 bit floats.

Comment: Thanks, `-arch compute_35` fixes it. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for half floats requires cuda architecture greater than or equal to 3.5. You need to compile with the -arch compute_35 flag to enable the corresponding instructions.